# cURL returns 302, whereas a browser returns 200

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-302

I have a script that uses a load of cURLs to log into a site and submit a series of forms, however this has recently stopped working due to the cURL requests returning 302s and redirecting to a block/endpoint page. If I do the same actions with a browser, I there are no redirects, just a 200 OK.

My cURL is using the cookie returned by the login process, so I don't think that the session is being dropped.

I'd originally thought that a CSRF Token (of some kind) was missing, given the redirect location, and that later forms in the process (using the browser) contain a hidden CSRF Token field, but the URL requires no posted data.

The cURL and response are as follows:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://*******.********.co.uk/Dispatcher?menuid=pos_home'); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$content = curl_exec ($ch);
echo "CURL INFO : <BR/><pre>" ;
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
```

which returns:

```
Array
(
[url] => https://*******.********.co.uk/Dispatcher?menuid=pos_home
[content_type] => text/html
[http_code] => 302
[header_size] => 253
[request_size] => 332
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 20
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0.142718
[namelookup_time] => 2.4E-5
[connect_time] => 2.4E-5
[pretransfer_time] => 9.0E-5
[size_upload] => 43
[size_download] => 327
[speed_download] => 2291
[speed_upload] => 301
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => 43
[starttransfer_time] => 0.142659
[redirect_time] => 0
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_ip] => nnn.nnn.nnn.nn
[primary_port] => 443
[local_ip] => nnn.nnn.nnn.nn
[local_port] => 53154
[redirect_url] => https://*******.********.co.uk/Dispatcher?menuid=badorMissingCSRFT
```

)

If anyone has any ideas why or how a server can give a different response for a cURL to a browser request, I'd be very grateful - thanks.of

Comment: Contact the site and ask what they require for your script to work.

Comment: _“If anyone has any ideas why or how a server can give a different response for a cURL to a browser request”_ – any number of possible reasons, starting with something trivial as the User Agent, to more elaborate reasons for classifying your request as not coming from a “browser”. If that site seems to take measures against what you are trying to do, then that might be a sign they don’t _want_ you to do it …

Answer (score 3):

You need to follow the redirection:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Other causes for not following a redirection:

> 4.14 Redirects work in browser but not with curl!
>
> curl supports HTTP redirects fine (see item 3.8). Browsers generally support at least two other ways to perform redirects that curl does not:
>
> Meta tags. You can write a HTML tag that will cause the browser to redirect to another given URL after a certain time.
>
> Javascript. You can write a Javascript program embedded in a HTML page that redirects the browser to another given URL.
>
> There is no way to make curl follow these redirects. You must either manually figure out what the page is set to do, or you write a script that parses the results and fetches the new URL.

source: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Redirects_work_in_browser_but_no

Answer (score 2):

curl with -L or --location option to follow the redirect.

`curl -L google.com`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the server started checking the `User-Agent:` or the `Referer:` HTTP headers.

Try to sniff the requests sent by your browser (the Developer Tools of the modern browsers tell you how the request looks like) and update the `cUrl` code to match the request sent by the browser.

Also consider the suggestions you received in the comments of the question (ask the site owner or just stop harvesting their site automatically).

Comment: Thanks @axaic - I was thinking along the same lines when I woke up a bit earlier and tried those settings before seeing your response. Unfortunately no luck. We've been using this crawler for a number of years, the site owner knew, and turned a blind eye, allowing us a sensible number of requests per day (which wasn't exceeded) - there's been a change of ownership on the site, so likely a change in policy/heart.

Comment: Curl does not follow redirects by default, as specified on the official page

Comment: Well, that calls for setting `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` as explained in [this aswer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29021711/4265352).